# PColor Trouble-how to set specific colors for specific ranges

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar

I am using pcolor to plot matrix X, which has dimensions (286,64) and values ranging from 0 to 20. How do I set specific colors to specific ranges, ie 0-0.5, white; 0.5-1.0, red; 1.0-2.0, orange, ... 15-20, blue? Every time I try to do that using contours and pcolor, the color bar ranges do not align with the tick marks, and the tick marks change from plot to plot, even though I hardwire them in the code.

Thanks?

Comment: Can you share a minimal working example?

Answer (score 0):

To specify colors to ranges that are not equally distant, you can either edit the colormap manually, or convert your matrix to an index of range matrix, then define you own colormap. Here is a simple example:

```
X = randi([0 20],28,64);
C = zeros(size(X)); % the ranges matrix
color_shift = [0 5 11 12]; % the values where the color changes
for k = 1:numel(color_shift)
    C(X>color_shift(k)) = k;
end
% your colormap
cmap = [0.8 0.2 0 % 0 - 5
        1 0.5 0 % 5 - 11
        0.5 0 0.5 % 11 - 12
        0.3 0.3 1]; % 12 - 20
pcolor(C)
colormap(cmap)
ch = colorbar;
% setting the ticks on the colorbar:
ch.Ticks =  0:numel(color_shift);
ch.TickLabels = [color_shift max(X(:))];
```

and you will get somthing like this:
[image: custom colormap]